# C++ how to check if a template class parameter's member variable is accessible (friendship considered)?

Tags: c++, c++20

I am trying something similar to this, i.e. checking if an accessible member exists before accessing it:

```
template<class T> concept IsA_ = requires (T t) { t.a; };

class A {
    friend class Friend;
    bool a;
 };

class Friend {

    template<class T> requires IsA_<T>
    void foo() { T{}.a = true; }

    void bar() { foo<A>(); } <--- "the associated constraints are not satisfied"
};
```

The code does not compile due to the concept *IsA_* not being fulfilled.

Although *A*'s member *a* is perfectly accessible from within *Friend*, the concept does not agree.

Is there a way to make this work?

**Note:** Changing member *a* to be a public member is not a solution.

**Note:** Changing member *a* to be a protected member and then letting *Friend* inherit from *A* is not a solution.

**Note:** Letting *IsA_* check for any private member *a* is not a solution.

**Note:** Letting *IsA_* check if *T* is of type *class A* is not a solution (*IsA_* refers to a set of properties rather than a fixed structure).

Comment: The evaluation of a concept, for a specific set of parameters, must *always* give the same answer. It can't give different answers in different places. Accessibility at the location of a concept's use is therefore irrelevant and not something that can be tested for.

Comment: @NicolBolas Thanks! That surely explains the behavior I observed, i.e. _Although A's member a is perfectly accessible from within Friend, the concept does not agree_. It does not answer the actual question though. I was hoping for some SFINAE/std::enable_if magic.

Comment: @songyuanyao Yes, good catch. It seems I simplified my actual code a bit too much. But it does not address the problem at hand.